# Facebook Graph API Really Slow

Tags: facebook, http, facebook-graph-api

When I make a Facebook Graph Request through HTTP, it is really slow.

To get 30KB of data takes nearly 4 seconds on a 2Mbps line.

I used a Chrome extension to measure the page load time and the `request` took over 3000ms.

[image: Chrome graph page load times...]

**Is this normal speed and, if not... How can I speed up my Graph requests?**

Answer (score 0):

By using [batch requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) or [realtime updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/)